# Using Javascript's getElementsByName and outputting a result using getElementById

Tags: javascript, html, input

I am having trouble grabbing multiple input's using the inputs name and adding multiplications to them like below. Is there another way I can do this without using **getElementById** ?

```
<input type="number" name="test1" id="RoundInput1">
<input type="number" name="test2" id="RoundInput2">

<button onclick="GetTheResults()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo">Click the button to change the text in this paragraph.</p>

<script>
x = document.getElementsByName("test1").value;
z = document.getElementsByName("test2").value;
var Savings = x + z;
function GetTheResults() {
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Savings;
}
</script>
```

Please note I have also tried the following:

```
x = document.getElementsByName("test1")[0].value;
z = document.getElementsByName("test2")[0].value;
```

Comment: Note, that you load the values of test1 and test2 just once. By putting the the variables x, z and Savings in the function GetTheResults it will work.

Comment: You are only declaring your function `GetTheResults`, not actually calling it. To call it, just add ```GetTheResults()``` before your `</script>` tag

Comment: Actually, it gets called by an onclick event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the `document.getElementsByName()` calls into the function. You will also need to use `parseInt()` to convert the inputs into integer values. As the name `getElementsByName` implies, the returned value is an array of all found elements; in your case you will need to access the first element of the returned array for your addition.

**Code**

```js
function GetTheResults() {
  x = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("test1")[0].value);
  z = parseInt(document.getElementsByName("test2")[0].value);
  var Savings = x + z;

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Savings;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" name="test1" id="RoundInput1">
<input type="number" name="test2" id="RoundInput2">
<button onclick="GetTheResults()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo">Click the button to change the text in this paragraph.</p>
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work. And also thank you for the explanation.
This was just an example I used for StackOverFlow, but it looks like I have about 50 calls to move into my function from what you have stated. So I may be back. Haha.

Comment: @Dayley you are welcome and thanks for accepting! Sure, feel free to ask again :-)

Comment: Hi again SaschaM, do you have any means to contact you so I could possibly run a large section of code by you that contain some of what you stated above? With it being a page of code I doubt I would get many replies on here from people.

Comment: @Dayley [let's discuss this in a chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166672/49208927-getelementsbyname)

Comment: Okay. Joined. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="number" name="test1" id="RoundInput1">
<input type="number" name="test2" id="RoundInput2">

<button onclick="GetTheResults()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo">Click the button to change the text in this paragraph.</p>

<script>
    function GetTheResults() {
        x = document.getElementsByName("test1")[0].value;
        // x = document.getElementById("RoundInput1").value;

        z = document.getElementsByName("test2")[0].value;
        // z = document.getElementById("RoundInput2").value;

        var Savings = parseInt(x) + parseInt(z);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Savings;
    }
</script>
```